# Overridden Font property in a custom usercontrol not being saved in designer file

Tags: properties, fonts, show

I have a custom user Progress Bar control and have overridden its Font property in the process of displaying text.

When I drop a copy of my usercontrol onto a form, I can set the Font property just fine, but I don't see the value I set for 'Font' showing up in my form's designer file. When I compile/run my app, the value I entered is lost.

Here is the code as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProgressBarWithText
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Control that extends the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar with
    /// the ability to overlay the percentage or a text message.
    /// </summary>
    [Description(
        "Control that extends the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar with the ability to overlay the Text."),
    DefaultProperty("TextVisible"),
    DefaultEvent("TextChanged")]
    public class ProgressBarWithText : ProgressBar
    {
        private const int WM_PAINT = 0x0F;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when the visibility of the percentage text is changed.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Raised when the visibility of the percentage text is changed."),
        Category("Property Changed")]
        public event EventHandler TextVisibleChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when the text has changed.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Raised when the text has changed."),
        Category("Property Changed")]
        public event EventHandler TextChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when the font has changed.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Raised when the font has changed."),
        Category("Property Changed")]
        public event EventHandler FontChanged;

        //private ContentAlignment m_p_align;
        private Font m_Font;
        private Color m_overlayColor;
        private StringFormat m_stringFormat;
        private string m_Text;
        private bool m_TextVisible;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of a ProgressbarWithPercentage.
        /// </summary>
        public ProgressBarWithText()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_overlayColor = Color.White;
            m_stringFormat = new StringFormat();
            m_TextVisible = true;
            m_stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            m_stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            if (m_Font == null)
                m_Font = SystemFonts.DialogFont;
        }

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or Sets the Font of the Text being displayed.
        /// </summary>
        [Bindable(true),
        Browsable(true),
        Category("Appearance"),
        Description("Get or Sets the Font of the Text being displayed."),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public override Font Font
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Font;
            }
            set
            {
                if (m_Font != value)
                {
                    m_Font = value;
                    Invalidate();
                    OnFontChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Color that is used to draw the text over a filled section of the progress bar.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Description("The Color that is used to draw the text over a filled section of the progress bar."),
        Category("Appearance"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
        public Color OverlayColor
        {
            get { return m_overlayColor; }
            set
            {
                if (m_overlayColor != value)
                    m_overlayColor = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Text being displayed.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Category("Appearance"),
        Description("The Text to be displayed or if left null will display a percentage"),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_Text != "") return m_Text;
                return Value.ToString() + "%";
            }

            set
            {
                if (m_Text != value)
                {
                    m_Text = value;
                    Invalidate();
                    OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the percentage will be displayed.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Description("Indicates whether the percentage will be displayed on the progress bar."),
        Category("Appearance"),
        DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool TextVisible
        {
            get { return m_TextVisible; }
            set
            {
                if (m_TextVisible != value)
                {
                    m_TextVisible = value;
                    OnTextVisibleChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        public new int Value
        {
            get { return base.Value; }
            set
            {
                if (base.Value != value)
                {
                    base.Value = value;

                    /* Needed for XP. Downside is control will be drawn twice
                     * when value coincides with one that the system uses for
                     * repaint. Could maybe use Environment.OSVersion to check? */
                    if (m_TextVisible)
                        Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Event Handlers

        protected virtual void OnTextVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler eh = TextVisibleChanged;
            if (eh != null)
                eh(this, e);
        }

        protected virtual void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler eh = TextChanged;
            if (eh != null)
                eh(this, e);
        }

        protected virtual void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler eh = FontChanged;
            if (eh != null)
                eh(this, e);
        }

        #endregion Event Handlers

        private void ShowText()
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            {
                // Draw left side
                Region regionLeft = new Region(new RectangleF(
                    ClientRectangle.X,
                    ClientRectangle.Y,
                    (ClientRectangle.Width * base.Value) / 100,
                    ClientRectangle.Height));
                using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(m_overlayColor))
                {
                    graphics.Clip = regionLeft;
                    graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, ClientRectangle, m_stringFormat);
                }
                // Draw right side
                Region regionRight = new Region(ClientRectangle);
                regionRight.Exclude(regionLeft);
                using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
                {
                    graphics.Clip = regionRight;
                    graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, ClientRectangle, m_stringFormat);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m_TextVisible && m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
                ShowText();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is what is saved in the design file after the 'font' property has been changed:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            this.progressBarWithText1 = new ProgressBarWithText.ProgressBarWithText();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // trackBar1
            // 
            this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 104);
            this.trackBar1.Maximum = 100;
            this.trackBar1.Name = "trackBar1";
            this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(596, 45);
            this.trackBar1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_Scroll);
            // 
            // progressBarWithText1
            // 
            this.progressBarWithText1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.progressBarWithText1.Name = "progressBarWithText1";
            this.progressBarWithText1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(596, 85);
            this.progressBarWithText1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.progressBarWithText1.Text = "foo";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(621, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.progressBarWithText1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.trackBar1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
        private ProgressBarWithText.ProgressBarWithText progressBarWithText1;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no parameters set for progressBarWithText1 for the font property. Is there a way to force them to be saved without having to manually set them or is there something I am doing wrong and need further instruction on?

Thank you for your time into this. God Bless,

Craig

Ps. This control is not entirely finished. I am just writing it now and got hung up on this.

Comment: Hey I figured it out! I wasn't using Virtual, New, nor Override keywords effectively and I learned how to directly access the Font property of the progressbar control. I bet you guys figured all this out and was letting me think it through. Totally awesome! How did you guys get to be so smart? Well anyway, thanks for letting me learn from the best teacher of all. God bless! Craig. (Now, how do I close this question again?)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to the question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProgressBarWithText
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Control that extends the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar with
    /// the ability to overlay the percentage or a text message.
    /// </summary>
    [Description(
        "Control that extends the System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar with the ability to overlay the Text."),
    DefaultProperty("TextVisible"),
    DefaultEvent("TextChanged")]

    public class ProgressBarWithText : ProgressBar
    {
        private const int WM_PAINT = 0x0F;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when the visibility of the percentage text is changed.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Raised when the visibility of the percentage text is changed."),
        Category("Property Changed")]
        public event EventHandler TextVisibleChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when the text has changed.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Description("Raised when the text has changed."),
        Category("Property Changed")]
        public new event EventHandler TextChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when the font has changed.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Description("Raised when the font has changed."),
        Category("Property Changed")]
        public new event EventHandler FontChanged;

        //private ContentAlignment m_p_align;
        private Color m_overlayColor;
        private StringFormat m_stringFormat;
        private string m_Text;
        private bool m_TextVisible;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of a ProgressbarWithPercentage.
        /// </summary>
        public ProgressBarWithText()
        {
            m_overlayColor = Color.White;
            m_stringFormat = new StringFormat();
            m_TextVisible = true;
            m_stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            m_stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        }

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or Sets the Font of the Text being displayed.
        /// </summary>
        [Bindable(true),
        Browsable(true),
        Category("Appearance"),
        Description("Get or Sets the Font of the Text being displayed."),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public override Font  Font
        {
            get 
            { 
                return base.Font;
            }
            set 
            { 
                base.Font = value;
                Invalidate();
                OnFontChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Color that is used to draw the text over a filled section of the progress bar.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Description("The Color that is used to draw the text over a filled section of the progress bar."),
        Category("Appearance"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
        public Color OverlayColor
        {
            get { return m_overlayColor; }
            set
            {
                if (m_overlayColor != value)
                    m_overlayColor = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Text being displayed.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Category("Appearance"),
        Description("The Text to be displayed or if left null will display a percentage"),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_Text != "") return m_Text;
                return Value.ToString() + "%";
            }

            set
            {
                if (m_Text != value)
                {
                    m_Text = value;
                    Invalidate();
                    OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the percentage will be displayed.
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true),
        Description("Indicates whether the Text will be displayed on the progress bar."),
        Category("Appearance"),
        DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool TextVisible
        {
            get { return m_TextVisible; }
            set
            {
                if (m_TextVisible != value)
                {
                    m_TextVisible = value;
                    OnTextVisibleChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        public new int Value
        {
            get { return base.Value; }
            set
            {
                if (base.Value != value)
                {
                    base.Value = value;

                    /* Needed for XP. Downside is control will be drawn twice
                        * when value coincides with one that the system uses for
                        * repaint. Could maybe use Environment.OSVersion to check? */
                    if (m_TextVisible)
                        Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Event Handlers

        protected virtual void OnTextVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler eh = TextVisibleChanged;
            if (eh != null)
                eh(this, e);
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler eh = TextChanged;
            if (eh != null)
                eh(this, e);
        }

        protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler eh = FontChanged;
            if (eh != null)
                eh(this, e);
        }

        #endregion Event Handlers

        private void ShowText()
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            {
                // Draw left side
                Region regionLeft = new Region(new RectangleF(
                    ClientRectangle.X,
                    ClientRectangle.Y,
                    (ClientRectangle.Width * base.Value) / 100,
                    ClientRectangle.Height));
                using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(m_overlayColor))
                {
                    graphics.Clip = regionLeft;
                    graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, ClientRectangle, m_stringFormat);
                }
                // Draw right side
                Region regionRight = new Region(ClientRectangle);
                regionRight.Exclude(regionLeft);
                using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
                {
                    graphics.Clip = regionRight;
                    graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, ClientRectangle, m_stringFormat);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m_TextVisible && m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
                ShowText();
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to learn more about the Virtual, New, and Override, you can find them on the [Understanding C#](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/10/understanding-c-using-virtual.html) web-site.

Thanks for your time.

God Bless,

Craig